# Possible to create a static lighting effect overlay using HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a static lighting effect overlay using HTML/CSS.

What I have is a pure HTML5/JS app that consists on most pages of a top navigation bar and a series of cards in the body that are transitioned through using swipe gestures.  These are all gray over a black background.

What I'd like to accomplish is have a sort of spot light gradient in the center of the screen that only effects the divs on the page and not the black background.  This spotlight would be fixed so that when swiping through cards, it remains in the center of the screen.

I know I could overlay a div with a spotlight image as its background, but obviously that would mess up clicking/swiping on the page.  And it would effect the black background.

Anyone have experience doing something like this?

Comment: What about an absolute positioned div with a radial css3 gradient?

Comment: But then how to handle button clicks and swipe gestures being made to underlying divs?  Or keeping the gradient from effecting the black background?

Comment: It might be oversimplifying, but is there anyway you can build the spotlight into the card divs themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple CSS solution** (no events required)

- Create a full-page-width bg image with the spotlight gradient.
- Give each div this bg image, with a `background-attachment` value of `fixed`.

No matter where each div happens to be on the page at the time, it will act as a window through which you can see part of the spotlight gradient. In effect, the bg image stays fixed in place while the div moves over it.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/janK3/1/), and the same demo with [heavily-rounded corners](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/Ypn2V/).

Alternately, it might be possible to give each div the same radial gradient in CSS (also fixed), rather than creating a static image file.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Worked off your fiddle demo to create what I was trying to accomplish:  http://jsfiddle.net/nimbus510/NAjAk/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an absolute positioned div with a gradient. For passing through that div events   use css property `pointer-events` (not supported by IE) or see that resource: http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Comment: That solves the events issue, but what about having the gradient only effect the divs on the page and not the solid black background?

Comment: It very depends on layout. Maybe try to use CSS Mask?